# How to convert from SQLCHAR to string in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a `SQLCHAR` to `string`, but I couldn't find a resource in the Net.

Any great suggestion, please?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: can you check what typdef SQLCHAR is on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQLCHAR` is just a typedef for `char`, so this should work:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << nameOfYourVariable;
string s;
ss >> s;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
SQLCHAR c[256];
string str((const char*)c);
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends of how is this `typedef` defined on your system. Most probably

```
typedef char SQLCHAR
```

so then you can write:

```
const SQLCHAR* name = "name";
std::string sName( name);
```